# should I use junction table or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, relationship

I'm developing a site using asp.net mvc5 and I'm working with a dba who has  a long experience in the field .
we had a conflict about the following relation between the following tables.

```
Award table
-ID
-.. the table fields
-supplierID
-employeeID
-otherID

Supplier
-ID
-.. the table fields

employee table
-ID
-.. the table fields

other table
-ID
-.. the table fields
```

the last three rows in the awards table are the types of beneficiaries of the award. and u can't have multiple beneficiaries.

so my suggestion was to use linking table "beneficiary" to link between the different "beneficiaries" and "awards" table.

what u think ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @ZoharPele I edited the schema I had it wrong the frst time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "one-of" relationship.  This is tricky in SQL and the method of using three columns is a good way of doing it.  Why?  It allows proper foreign key declarations.

I would look for a table definition such as this:

```
create table Awards (
    awardsId int identity primary key,
    . . .
    supplierId int,
    employeeID int,
    otherID int,
    beneficiaryType as (case when supplierId is not null then 'S'
                             when employeeId is not null then 'E'
                             when otherId is not null then 'O'
                        end),
    constraint chk_beneficiary
        check ( (supplierId is not null and employeeId is null and otherid is null) or
                (supplierId is null and employeeId is not null and otherid is null) or
                (supplierId is null and employeeId is null and otherid is not null)
             ),      
    constraint fk_awards_supplierId foreign key (supplierId) references Suppliers(supplierId),
    constraint fk_awards_employeeId foreign key (employeeId) references Employees(employeeId),
    constraint fk_awards_supplierId foreign key (otherId) references Others(otherId)
);
```

If it is really unusual that another type of beneficiary is added, then database maintenance is not a big problem.

I should note that you can also do the above with "generic" columns and persisted computed columns:

```
create table Awards (
    awardsId int identity primary key,
    . . .
    beneficiaryType char(1) not null,
    beneficiaryId int not null,
    constraint chk_awards_beneficiaryType check (beneficiaryType in ('E', 'S', 'O')),
    supplierId as (case when beneficiaryType = 'S' then beneficiaryId end) persisted,
    employeeID as (case when beneficiaryType = 'E' then beneficiaryId end) persisted,
    otherID as (case when beneficiaryType = 'O' then beneficiaryId end) persisted,
    constraint fk_awards_supplierId foreign key (supplierId) references Suppliers(supplierId),
    constraint fk_awards_employeeId foreign key (employeeId) references Employees(employeeId),
    constraint fk_awards_supplierId foreign key (otherId) references Others(otherId)
);
```

Because the computed columns have to be persisted in order to be used as foreign keys, this does not save space.  However, adding a new type is a matter of just doing:

- Changing the `check` constraint for `beneficiaryType`
- Adding a new computed column
- Adding a new foreign key constraint

This does require that all ids to all tables have the same type.  However, I (almost) always use identity columns as primary keys, so this is true automatically in any database I design.

Comment: This answer is on point. Thnx for the clear explanation. And what i was complaining about that it seemed poor structure for me to check the three columns in the table to see what is the beneficiary type. But with beneficiaryType column and the constraints it looks good. Thnx again